# Extract hardware specifications from a full text in node js

Tags: node.js

How can I extract hardware specifications (Ram, processor, storage, connectivity) from a full text document in node js?
Does exists some module that I can use and configure or something that I can partially rewrite to fit my necessity?

/*** UPDATE

Example

> Entrando nelle specifiche, siamo ovviamente di fronte a un tablet
>   senza troppe pretese, equipaggiato con pannello da 7 pollici
>   (risoluzione 1280 x 720 pixel), SoC Bay Trail T Z3735G, 1GB di RAM e
>   Storage flash di 16 GB. Il WinBook non supporta il 3G tuttavia offre
>   connettività WiFi, Bluetooth oltre a supportare USB, HDMI e doppia
>   fotocamera da 2 Mp.
>
> Un prodotto davvero interessante per questo prezzo che da noi sarebbe
>   di meno di 50 Euro.

What I want

```
CPU: SoC Bay Trail T Z3735G
Ram: 1gb
Display: 7", 1280 x 720 pixel
Storage: 16gb
Connectivity: Wifi, Bluetooth, USB, HDMI
Photocamera: 2mp
```

Thanks

Comment: It would help to be more specific. Try to give a sample text and examples of what you expect to extract from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’ll need several solutions for this. Several of the specs you are looking for are predictable enough that you could probably get away with using regular expressions to make a pretty good guess based on context and catch them: Storage, connectivity, camera, RAM, and display size & resolution.

I’m not sure whether you’re trying to parse descriptions of tablets only, or several kinds of devices, but using a regular expression to identify what kind of device first, and then set different regex parameters to catch the properties mentioned above according to the device category.

**Update:**

For example, you can use this regex for identifying RAM and Storage: `/(\d{1,4}) *(gb|mb)/gi` See how it matches your query [at this link.](http://regex101.com/r/zK6nJ3/1) Then it’s only a question of parsing the numbers in each match and making an educated guess (i.e. the larger number is likeliest to be storage, while the lower number is RAM).

You could also use `/(\d{1,4}) *(gb|mb) *(ram)*/gi` which returns true even if *RAM* is not found. This wouldn’t match your query because it says *1GB di RAM*, but then *di* is a word you could safely strip out (it means *of* in Italian, correct?).

Alternatively, something like `/(\d{1,4}) *(gb|mb) *\w* *(ram)*/gi` [would match your query](http://regex101.com/r/fT8fI2/1) without having to strip *di* out at all. Note in the link how this regex matches both instances of #GB, but only the first one includes `RAM` in the match. That makes it even easier to identify which figure refers to the RAM and which refers to storage.

**/Update**

---

Figuring out the CPU is going to be more challenging because that’s not a pattern that’s as easy to predict. We had a similar problem recently and used [natural](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural)’s `.BayesClassifier()` method to match a query with the entry that it more closely resembles. Unfortunately, this means you’d need to maintain a reasonably up-to-date database of popular CPUs against which to test your user’s query.

Something like this:

```
var natural = require('natural');

var classifier = new natural.BayesClassifier();

classifier.addDocument('SoC Bay Trail T Z3735G', 101);
classifier.addDocument('ARM Cortex-A5', 102);
classifier.addDocument('Intel Core i3-3217U', 103);
classifier.addDocument('AMD Micro-6400T', 104);

classifier.train();

var query = 'Entrando nelle specifiche, siamo ovviamente di fronte a un tablet senza troppe pretese, equipaggiato con pannello da 7 pollici (risoluzione 1280 x 720 pixel), SoC Bay Trail T Z3735G, 1GB di RAM e Storage flash di 16 GB. Il WinBook non supporta il 3G tuttavia offre connettività WiFi, Bluetooth oltre a supportare USB, HDMI e doppia fotocamera da 2 Mp. Un prodotto davvero interessante per questo prezzo che da noi sarebbe di meno di 50 Euro.'

var output = classifier.getClassifications(query);

console.log(output);
```

Outputs this:

```
[ { label: '101', value: 0.4 },
  { label: '102', value: 0.0125 },
  { label: '103', value: 0.0125 },
  { label: '104', value: 0.0125 } ]
```

Of course, with potentially hundreds (or even thousands) of records to match against, those `value` properties will be much smaller (I should know, my partner and I are matching user queries to a list of 1200+ bus stop names), but it should in many cases help you identify a definitive match.

I can think of two ways to help the classifier make a better match:

1. Make separate classifiers for each device type: That way, if you know you’re likely looking for a tablet processor, you only match against the tablet CPU classifier.
2. Remove unnecessary cruft from the user query, like the pieces you’ve already identified as belonging to other specs via regex, and common words that don’t help you to identify hardware (ovviamente, support, il, interessante, etc.)

Comment: thank you so much Alfonso, very very very good answer! That's the explanation that I was looking for... Can you put also an example of the regex that I must use to match for example the ram?

Comment: I updated my response. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Hey, @UsiUsi. Do you think I’ve answered your question? If so, mark it as answered. Otherwise, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for delay! Yes! Thank you very much for your explanation! Regards